# Losing LazyTreeGrid functionality after applying noscroll attribute

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I am using the `dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid` widget to display a simple tree grid shown below:

```js
dojo.require("dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid");
dojo.require("dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");

dojo.ready(function(){
    /* set up data store */
    var data = { identifier: 'name',
        label: 'name',
        items: [
          { name:'Africa', type:'continent', children:[
          { name:'Egypt', type:'country' },
          { name:'Kenya', type:'country', children:[
          { name:'Nairobi', type:'city', adults: 70400, popnum: 2940911 },
          { name:'Mombasa', type:'city', adults: 294091, popnum: 707400 } ]
          },
          { name:'Sudan', type:'country', children:
          { name:'Khartoum', type:'city', adults: 480293, popnum: 1200394 }
          } ]
          },
          { name:'Asia', type:'continent', children:[
              { name:'China', type:'country' },
              { name:'India', type:'country' },
              { name:'Russia', type:'country' },
              { name:'Mongolia', type:'country' } ]
          } ]        
    };
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});
        var model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({store: store, childrenAttrs: ['children']});

    /* set up layout */
    var layout = [
      {name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '10em'},
      {name: 'Type', field: 'type', width: '15em'},
      {name: 'Population', field: 'population', width: '15em'},
      {name: 'Area', field: 'area', width: '15em'}
    ];

    /* create a new grid: */
    var grid = new dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        treeModel: model,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px'
      }, document.createElement('div'));

    /* append the new grid to the div */
    dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

    /* Call startup() to render the grid */
    grid.startup();
});
```

```css
#grid {
    width: 43em;
    height: 15em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="gridDiv"></div>
</body>
```

I am trying to lock the first column in place, so that you can still scroll horizontally along the other columns in the table. I accomplish this by changing the way I define `layout` and adding `noscroll:true` to it:

```
var layout = [
  {cells:[ [
    {name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '10em'},
    ] ], noscroll:true
  },
  {cells:[ [
    {name: 'Type', field: 'type', width: '15em'},
    {name: 'Population', field: 'population', width: '15em'},
    {name: 'Area', field: 'area', width: '15em'}
    ] ]
  }
];
```

```js
dojo.require("dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid");
dojo.require("dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");

dojo.ready(function(){
    /* set up data store */
    var data = { identifier: 'name',
        label: 'name',
        items: [
          { name:'Africa', type:'continent', children:[
          { name:'Egypt', type:'country' },
          { name:'Kenya', type:'country', children:[
          { name:'Nairobi', type:'city', adults: 70400, popnum: 2940911 },
          { name:'Mombasa', type:'city', adults: 294091, popnum: 707400 } ]
          },
          { name:'Sudan', type:'country', children:
          { name:'Khartoum', type:'city', adults: 480293, popnum: 1200394 }
          } ]
          },
          { name:'Asia', type:'continent', children:[
              { name:'China', type:'country' },
              { name:'India', type:'country' },
              { name:'Russia', type:'country' },
              { name:'Mongolia', type:'country' } ]
          } ]        
    };
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});
        var model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({store: store, childrenAttrs: ['children']});

    /* set up layout */
    var layout = [
      {cells:[ [
        {name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '10em'},
        ] ], noscroll:true
      },
      {cells:[ [
        {name: 'Type', field: 'type', width: '15em'},
        {name: 'Population', field: 'population', width: '15em'},
        {name: 'Area', field: 'area', width: '15em'}
        ] ]
      }
    ];

    /* create a new grid: */
    var grid = new dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        treeModel: model,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px'
      }, document.createElement('div'));

    /* append the new grid to the div */
    dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

    /* Call startup() to render the grid */
    grid.startup();
});
```

```css
#grid {
    width: 43em;
    height: 15em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="gridDiv"></div>
</body>
```

After doing this, you can see that the left most column is locked in place. However, I am not able to expand the fields in this column to see their children (Egypt, Kenya, Sudan, etc.) anymore. Is this a bug with the widget? Or am I going about doing this the wrong way? Are there other widgets I could use to achieve this same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that seems easily feasible with dgrid. Two demos that you can look into: http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/extensions/CompoundColumns_Tree.html and http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/complex_column.html.

To implement the locking of the column you set a style for its column set that determines its width. Perhaps you can achieve something similar with dojox.grid (instead of noscroll:true).

Here is an example, which is the CompoundColumns_Tree.html demo with a style that locks the first column.

```js
require(
{
 packages: [
  {
   name: 'dgrid',
   location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0'
  },
  {
   name: 'dstore',
   location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dstore/v1.1.1'
  }
 ]
}, 
[
  'dgrid/Tree',
  'dgrid/ColumnSet',
  'dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
  'dgrid/extensions/CompoundColumns',
  'dgrid/test/data/createHierarchicalStore',
  'dgrid/test/data/hierarchicalCountryData',
  'dojo/on'
], function (Tree, ColumnSet, OnDemandGrid, CompoundColumns, createHierarchicalStore, data, on) {
  var CompoundTree = OnDemandGrid.createSubclass([ Tree, CompoundColumns, ColumnSet ]);
  var store = createHierarchicalStore({ data: data });

  var columnSets = [
    [
      [
        {
          field: 'name',
          label: 'Name',
          renderExpando: true
        }
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        {
          label: 'Information',
          children: [
            {
              field: 'type',
              label: 'Type'
            }, {
              field: 'population',
              label: 'Population'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  ];

  var grid = new CompoundTree({
    columnSets: columnSets,
    collection: store.getRootCollection()
  }, 'grid');
});
```

```css
.dgrid {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.dgrid .dgrid-content .dgrid-cell {
  height: 24px;
}

.dgrid-column-set-0 {
  width: 25%;
}

.field-type {
  width: 150px;
}
.field-population {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0/css/skins/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0/css/dgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">


<div class="claro">
  <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the functionality I am looking for. Is it possible to do this using `dojox.grid.DataGrid`? I'm not too familiar with Dojo.. but isn't `DataGrid` the same thing as `dgrid` in versions >1.7.0 of the Dojo toolkit? I'm trying to avoid having dependencies on outside packages that are not included in the toolkit.

Comment: What you want may be possible with DataGrid but I'm not familiar with it and I don't know how to do it. According to the reference guide dojox.grid is deprecated and replaced by dgrid ot gridx. If you don't have code that relies heavily on dojox.grid it would be better to go with one of the actively maintained grid implementations for dojo. (Dgrid http://dgrid.io/ or gridx http://oria.github.io/gridx/)